# Finding results in a table based on multiple criteria

Tags: google-sheets

I'm struggling to find a solution to the following issue and hoping someone can help.

I have set up a simplified example of my database on: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jWvLXPoMfOrFrZf4QEW9SoCoX7b7X3vD4-ZXvuXy9w8/edit?usp=sharing

There are two tables. 1) On the left a static database, which is collected directly from clients through a Google Form. 2) On the right, a table managed by myself, where I input a date (G:G) and client name (H:H). When G and H are filled, I want the database to search for the result from the database in A:C.

I have complete the results in col I manually to demonstrate what the result should be, but I want to this be completed automatically. Essentially, based on the client name and date given in G:H, it will search A:C and provide the result in C:C where the date in G:G is after the date is A:A, but before the date of the next row associated with that client.

Can anyone assist with this? Thanks.

Comment: you are trying to join the name of the client with the time, to the seconds, like this: John44022.5682638889, what do you exactly want ? because as the left column has the time as 13:33, the right column have 13:38

Comment: The time shown in B and H is just for an example. In the real database, the times are random, not fixed to 13:33 and 13:38 as shown here.

Comment: but you want to match them and the name of the client ? like "John44022.5682638889" (the number after john is the date to the miliseconds)? because if you want, that's what you already have, in the sheet you shared, the error says:  Did not find value 'John44039.5682638889' in VLOOKUP evaluation.

Comment: I'm not entirely following that explanation. But as an example, let's use John. His opening data is from 08/07/2020 13:33:45, where he has registered 0.51. Then the next dataset for John is at 12/08/2020 13:33:49, when he registers 0.87. If the client name in G is John and the date is between 08/07/2020 13:33:45 and 12/08/2020 13:33:49, then the result is 0.51. If the date is after 12/08/2020 13:33:49 but before his next dataset on 22/08/2020 13:33:50, then the result is 0.87.

Comment: Your explanation right here is a bit messy. When you say dataset, are you are refering to a unique row? 

Could we say that you want the last record for a given day (column  H) of each name in column G? 
Is the result provided in the sheet correct?

Comment: @Raserhin. Yes dataset = unique row. Yes to your second question, on the given day in col H it would report the result from col C in col I of the clients name. Yes, the result in col I shown in the sheet is correct and shows what I am trying to achieve by formula

Answer (score 0):

I see that there is already an answer in the sheet that works fine using the [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) function:

```
=QUERY(A$2:C,"Select B where C = '"&G2&"' and A < "&H2&" Order by A desc limit 1",0)
```

[image: Result]